# How do I compare mlocate.db to what exists now?

Tags: centos, rm, lxc, locate

I ran `rm -rf` on `/var/cache/lxc`, not realizing it was full of symlinks.  I've lost a bunch of files, including most of /dev.  I have a `mlocate.db` from 16 hours ago.  How do I compare the list of files from `mlocate.db` to what still exists to get a complete list of what is missing?  `locate -e` says it will give me files that still exist, I basically need the opposite.

edit:
Thank you cas.  Took me a while, but I finally found the problem:

```
#mount | grep /var/cache/lxc
devtmpfs on /var/cache/lxc/fedora/x86_64/bootstrap/dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,seclabel,size=74173740k,nr_inodes=18543435,mode=755)
proc on /var/cache/lxc/fedora/x86_64/bootstrap/proc type proc (rw,relatime)
proc on /var/cache/lxc/yakkety/rootfs-amd64/proc type proc (rw,relatime)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Make a backup copy of `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db` **now**, before the mlocate updatedb cron job runs again.
2. Dump `mlocate.db` to a text file:

   `mlocate / | sort > /var/lib/mlocate/mlocate-old.txt`
3. Update your your mlocate.db.  How to do this varies slightly according to what kind of unix clone or linux distribution you're using.  e.g. on a Debian box, run `/etc/cron.daily/mlocate`, or just `updatedb.mlocate`.
4. Dump the new `mlocate.db` to a file:

   `mlocate / | sort > /var/lib/mlocate/mlocate-new.txt`.
5. See the changes with, e.g., `diff -u /var/lib/mlocate/mlocate-{old,new}.txt`.

   The output is likely to be huge, so redirect to a file or pipe into `less`.